# How many recipes can you make with only milk, eggs, butter, flour, sugar, and salt?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a SQL query that has me stumped.  Basically, I have a `Recipes` table that contains (as you've no doubt guessed,) many recipes.  I have an `Ingredients` table which contains all sorts of ingredients.  I have a `RecipeIngredients` table that links a recipe to what ingredients it uses.  Lastly, I have a `PopularIngredients` table (it's actually a view, but who cares?) that contains the most popular ingredients people might have in their kitchen:

```
CREATE Table Recipes
(
  RecipeId int4,
  Title varchar(100)
);

CREATE Table Ingredients
(
  IngredientId int4,
  Name varchar(100)
);

CREATE Table RecipeIngredients
(
  RecipeId int4,
  IngredientId int4,
  Amount int2
);

CREATE Table PopularIngredients
(
  IngredientId int4
);
```

My goal is to get a list of all recipes that use *only* popular ingredients.

**A SQL Fiddle with sample data can be found [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/9278b/6).**

What I'm looking for is a query that will return *Chicken Salad* and *Pancakes*.  *Aligator Burgers* would not be returned, since it uses *aligator* which is not a popular ingredient.

I've tried a few things involving sub-selects and the `ALL` keyword, but haven't had any luck.  I've tried various inner and outer joins, but Recipe rows will still show up as long as at least one of its ingredients is popular.  Any help would be much appreciated!

I'm using Postgres 9.1.

Comment: This is a model question; I'm using it to show new posters how to do it right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This gets all recipes which have no ingredients that are not in the PopularIngredients table.

```
select * from Recipes r where not exists (
  select * from RecipeIngredients ri 
  left join PopularIngredients pi on pi.IngredientId=ri.IngredientId
  where ri.RecipeId=r.RecipeId and pi.IngredientId is null
)
```

Comment: Thanks!  I knew it would have some sort of `not exists` in there somewhere, but brain just wasn't working at optimal conditions..

Answer (score 5):

Used `WHERE NOT EXISTS` to ensure none of the ingredients used are missing from the PopularIngredients view:

```
SELECT R.*
FROM Recipes R
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM RecipeIngredients RI
    LEFT JOIN PopularIngredients P ON P.IngredientId = RI.IngredientId
    WHERE RI.RecipeId = R.RecipeId AND P.IngredientId IS NULL
)
```

Updated your [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/c3d01/4)

Answer (score 2):

```
select r.Title
  from Recipes r
  join RecipeIngredients ri
    on r.RecipeId = ri.RecipeId
  left outer join PopularIngredients pi
    on ri.IngredientId = pi.IngredientId
 group by r.Title
 having count( case when pi.IngredientId is null then 1 end )=0
```

or nearly the same

```
select r.Title
  from Recipes r
  join RecipeIngredients ri
    on r.RecipeId = ri.RecipeId
  left outer join PopularIngredients pi
    on ri.IngredientId = pi.IngredientId
 group by r.Title
 having count(pi.IngredientId)=count(ri.IngredientId)
```

Comment: I like this approach because it is more set-based.  However, the having clause should perhaps be "count(distinct)" rather than "count()" to take into account recipes where an ingredient might be included more than one time.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - ??? I don't see how adding DISTINCT can make any difference in the outcome, other than perhaps slowing it down a bit. If an ingredient appears twice in the recipe then the outer join will either succeed twice or fail twice as well. It still gives the correct result without the DISTINCT.

Comment: @dbenham . . . I think you're right.  If an ingredient appears multiple times in either or both tables, the counts are "wrong" but they still agree.